# Limpiar DataGrid para generar nueva venta C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

verán, mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy trabajando con dos formularios, ambos conectados a una base de datos SQL, mi primer formulario se llama: GENERAR; en el género una orden de servicio, y el segundo es CONSULTAR, donde visualizo todas las ordenes de servicio que se hayan emitido.

En el primer formulario tengo un botón que genera PDF de la orden generada.

El problema comienza cuando quiero generar una nueva orden de servicio, porque mi primer formulario aparece lleno de la orden anterior, y al generar el archivo pdf me imprime toda la tabla.

Lo que busco es vaciar de algún modo, o no mostrar el contenido de mi base de datos en el DataGrid del primer formulario, para cuando genere una nueva orden no me imprima toda la tabla.

Para generar los archivos PDF utilizo Crystal Reports.

Espero haya podido explicarme debidamente.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Como cargas tu datagrid? cual es el codigo que tenes?

Comment: No utilizo código para cargar los datagrid, lo hago de forma "Automatica" (no se si se diga de tal modo) Solo abro las tareas del DataGrid y le conecto con nuevos orígenes de datos.

Comment: Entonces deberias pasarle un parametro para que se cargue vacio?

Comment: como conectas al DataGrid con los datos? usas algun componente visual que arrastraste desde el toolbox

Comment: que relacion tiene el DataGrid con el reporte en Crystal? porque hasta donde entiendo el reporte deberias generarlo en base a los datos que obtienes desde la db no desde un grid en un form